# How to apply a function to the elements of a list with the "L /. x_ ->f[x]" notation?

Tags: functions, map

Suppose we have a list:

```
{5,6,7}
```

Suppose I have a function like `GCD[x,10]` and I want to apply it to the given list. I'm trying to do the following:

```
{5,6,7}/. x_ -> GCD[x,10]
```

Trying to accomplish:

```
{GCD[5,10],GCD[6,10],GCD[7,10]}
```

But it's not working. How can I apply a function to a list in this manner?

Comment: `{5, 6, 7} /.  x_?NumericQ -> GCD[x, 10]`; however, `GCD[#, 10]& /@ {5, 6, 7}` is more efficient; and since `GCD` is `Listable`, `GCD[{5, 6, 7}, 10]` is much more efficient.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, this is really nice. I'm curious about the following: `?` is a pattern test, right? Can we do it in a way that it doesn't test what is inside the list?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do in your comment. Provide a specific input and desired output.

Comment: @BobHanlon When we write `x_?NumericQ` it will pick any numeric elements of the set, right? What should we write for it to pick anything in the set?

Comment: `f /@ list` or the equivalent `Map[f, list] `

Comment: @BobHanlon But what if the function has two arguments?

Comment: `GCD` has two arguments and you've been shown how to handle it with `Map`. There are some variations if you are mapping onto various structures. See the documentation for `Map` and `Apply`

Comment: @BobHanlon I understand, but I am asking the following: How can I use `{5, 6, 7} /.  x_?NumericQ -> GCD[x, 10]` without the `?NumericQ`?

Comment: The right way to do this,imho, with replacement patterns is `Replace[list, x_ :> GCD[x,  10], 1]`. But Bob’s `GCD[list, 10]` or `f[#, 10]& /@ list if `f` is not listable would be how I do it normally.

Comment: Or since `GCD` is `Listable`: `{5, 6, 7} /.  {x__} :> GCD[{x}, 10]`

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

list = RandomInteger[{5, 15}, 10]

(* {5, 11, 14, 11, 15, 5, 12, 5, 5, 13} *)
```

Comparing the relative timing of the various methods using [`RepeatedTiming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html) (trimmed mean of timings for repeated evaluations)

```
r[1] = RepeatedTiming[GCD[list, 10]]

(* {2.80609*10^-6, {5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1}} *)

r[2] = RepeatedTiming[GCD[#, 10] & /@ list]

(* {5.36349*10^-6, {5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1}} *)

r[3] = RepeatedTiming[list /.  {x__} :> GCD[{x}, 10]]

(* {7.64871*10^-6, {5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1}} *)

r[4] = RepeatedTiming[Replace[list, x_ :> GCD[x, 10], 1]]

(* {5.95475*10^-6, {5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1}} *)

r[5] = RepeatedTiming[list /.  x_?NumericQ -> GCD[x, 10]]

(* {8.2377*10^-6, {5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1}} *)
```

Verifying that the results are identical

```
SameQ @@ (r[#][[2]] & /@ Range[5])

(* True *)
```

The times relative to the best time

```
(times = (r[#][[1]] & /@ Range[5]))/Min[times]

(* {1., 1.91138, 2.72575, 2.12208, 2.93565} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Map[GCD[#, 10] &, {5, 6, 7}]


(*  {5, 2, 1} *)
```

Have fun!